# AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, anaconda

I downloaded anaconda and when try to launch jupyter notebook using cmd, the error appear as AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'. I am launching jypyter by typing jupyter notebook in cmd in windows os. Thanks for solving my error

Comment: try launching it from anaconda shell

Comment: I run it using anaconda shell but the same thing happened

Answer (score 37):

I recommend you try this:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Based on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2990.

Comment: Is this supposed to work even without sudo? It doesn't work for me without sudo!

Comment: @Saurav This depends on the environment you are using. If `pip` refers to a global installation then you have to use `sudo`. If `pip` is running from within a `virtualenv` then it should work without (as it is installed for your user only).

Comment: Could you incorporate some information from the bug report link on github into your answer? If that issue got deleted that information would just be lost.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

1. Uninstall pip3

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3-pip
   ```
2. Go to your home directory

   ```
   cd $HOME
   ```
3. Search for any other pip3 links

   ```
   sudo find . -name 'pip3'
   ```
4. Delete all the links using `rm` if any were found
5. Download/Clone [pip from here](https://github.com/pypa/pip) (via `git` for example)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip
   ```
6. Go to the downloaded directory

   ```
   cd pip
   ```
7. Install pip3 (you might need to add `sudo` in front of it)

   ```
   python3 setup.py install
   ```

This will install the latest version of pip and remove the error without loss of any packages.

Comment: Thanks; this did the job for me too

Comment: Clearler instructions would be better. What exactly do you mean by finding any other pip3 links?

Comment: @Schütze It means that you should look if there are references to the old installation somewhere in your files and delete them before you install again. Therefore the `rm` command. `find` will look for files (including link) containing _pip3_ in the name.

Answer (score 4):

upgrading setuptools didn't work for me. I did reinstall pip,

```
git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip.git
cd pip
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Worked, thanks, but better work with a specific release branch than point ppl to master.  `git clone https://github.com/pypa/pip.git -b release/9.0.3 --single-branch && cd pip && python setup.py install`

Comment: re-checked - it didn't solve my issue.  Using a release branch still recommended ...

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with pip install. The following worked for me.

```
easy_install pip
easy_install setuptools
```

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885