# Trying to clean install python (anaconda), getting error related to prior installs

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Every time I do a clean install of anaconda I get the same lengthy error. I would optimally like to purge my computer of any python files. I have tried everything from removing the path variables, to scouring my computer for residual folders/files (aside from .anaconda I had no success here) to deleting the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python key in regedit. I believe this error started occuring when I tried to install a second version of python (I have the continuum installation). Any help would be amazing and greatly appreciated! `Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.21
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.1.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : C:\Users\John\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\John\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\John\.conda\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
      administrator : False
```

`$ C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py ..checkenv cmd.exe C:\Users\John\Anaconda3`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 167, in main
    import conda.cli.activate as activate
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\activate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..utils import shells
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .gateways.disk.read import compute_md5sum
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\read.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ...models.channel import Channel
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\models\channel.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .._vendor.auxlib.path import expand
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\path.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2985, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2971, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3013, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2544, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2118, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2058, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2087, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`
```

Comment: I have to ask: have you restarted your computer since installing?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't add that.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure pip and setuptools are up to date, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169218/attributeerror-namespacepath-object-has-no-attribute-sort) answer.

In the future, it may be useful to use `venv` to create a virtual environment that will help eliminate dependency headaches.

Create a new virtual environment like this:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Requires Python 3.3 or greater, but it looks like you're using 3.6 so you should be good to go. More info on `venv` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot even access pip. When I type python or pip into my anaconda prompt it says that they don't exist (I don't think its a problem with my PATH variables though, as I was under the impression that those are included in the anaconda prompt)

Comment: Try to figure out which python you're using. If you're using Cygwin, you can simply call `which python`. The Windows cmd has a similar command called `where`, so you'd call `where python`. Anaconda comes with pip, so you should see it in `C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip`. *My* python executable is in `C:\Anaconda3\python`, if that helps.

Comment: I managed to get python working , however I still get the same error and jupyter notebook won't run. I reinstalled anaconda and this time it decided (in the install wizard) that adding python to my PATH is fine (previously it always stated that this could lead to errors (not sure why this changed). Anyways  I'm running python 3.6.0 with anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit). I'm still getting this error:  AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort' I'm not sure what to do either :( I really don't want to reinstall windows.

Comment: Don't reinstall Windows; I'm sure it won't be necessary. If you google "Anaconda AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`", have you tried every single thing suggested on the front page?

Comment: Many people seem to be indicating it is a problem with `pip`, which would require an update or (at worst) a reinstall of `pip`, not Windows; reinstalling Windows is overkill. If you have another computer (or perhaps a virtual environment, Linux machine, etc.) try starting the whole process over on a different machine and pay close attention to each step you take: which version of each component you install and *every* command you run. If you have a list of commands and steps to reproduce you could add to your answer, it would be very helpful.